# AWS: What does 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

In security group, every inbound port I add, two rules are added, one for 0.0.0.0/0, the other ::/0. What do they each mean?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> The default route in Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4) is designated
>   as the zero-address 0.0.0.0/0 in CIDR notation, often called the
>   quad-zero route. The subnet mask is given as /0, which effectively
>   specifies all networks, and is the shortest match possible.

The other would be for IPv6

Source [Default Route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route)

AWS Documentation

[Security Groups for Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

> A security group acts as a virtual firewall for your instance to
>   control inbound and outbound traffic. When you launch an instance in a
>   VPC, you can assign the instance to up to five security groups.
>   Security groups act at the instance level, not the subnet level.
>   Therefore, each instance in a subnet in your VPC could be assigned to
>   a different set of security groups. If you don't specify a particular
>   group at launch time, the instance is automatically assigned to the
>   default security group for the VPC.
>
> For each security group, you add rules that control the inbound
>   traffic to instances, and a separate set of rules that control the
>   outbound traffic.

**Default Security Group for Your VPC**

> Your VPC automatically comes with a default security group. Each EC2
>   instance that you launch in your VPC is automatically associated with
>   the default security group if you don't specify a different security
>   group when you launch the instance.
>
> The following table describes the default rules for a default security
>   group.

**Inbound**

```
Source      The security group ID (sg-xxxxxxxx)
Protocol    All
Port Range  All
Comments    Allow inbound traffic from instances assigned to the same security group.
```

**Outbound**

```
Destination 0.0.0.0/0   
Protocol    All
Port Range  All
Comments    Allow all outbound IPv4 traffic.

Destination ::/0    
Protocol    All     
Port Range  All     
Comments    Allow all outbound IPv6 traffic. This rule is added by default if you create a VPC with an IPv6 CIDR block or if you associate an IPv6 CIDR block with your existing VPC.
```

[Recommended Network ACL Rules for Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_NACLs.html)

Answer (score 65):

0.0.0.0/0,::/0 - Means source can be any ip address, means from any system request is accepted, 0.0.0.0/0 represents ipv4 and ::/0 represents ipv6. To know CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing) representation see this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xsmbe5s6j0

Comment: Getting to know CIDR notation is key. Wikipedia has a helpful overview of the blocks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks

Answer (score 50):

0.0.0.0/0 refers to all IPv4 addresses and ::/0 refers All IPv6 addresses.

Comment: The accepted answer gives more detail and helps understanding. Stack Overflow is a strange place, they don't like discussion but do like this.

Comment: Have you thought about that people might not want an explanation but only the answer, great answer +1

Comment: I prefer short explanations even if detailed ones are still interesting

Comment: This IMO is the best answer. It answers the question exactly.

Answer (score 6):

[**0.0.0.0**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0#Routing) means that any **IP** either from a `local system` or from *anywhere* on the `internet` can access.

It is `everything else` **other** than what is `already` specified in **routing table**.

When we add `/0` is for the **IPv4** whereas `::/0` is for **IPv6** is known as [**CIDR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)

Coming back to your AWS part, when you define **[0.0.0.0/0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)** or **[::/0](https://serverfault.com/a/698372)** that means all the **IPv4** and **IPv6**  ranges respectively can access your AWS service(s).

Ranges for **IPv4** is from [**0.0.0.0**](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/security-interface-ipv4-ipv6-protocol.html) to [**255.255.255.255**](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/security-interface-ipv4-ipv6-protocol.html) where as **IPv6** have [**2^128**](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/what-you-need-know-about-ipv6) addresses.

Answer (score 5):

An IP address is built by 32 bits, the slash tells you how many bits are used to identify the network section, the rest of the bits are used for the host. For example, 255.0.0.0/8 tells you 8 bits are for the network and 24 are for the host, so you migth have 16777214 possible IPs comming from that 255 network.

In case of the notation 0.0.0.0/0, it means you dont use any identifier for the network, therefore you have the whole 32 bits for the IP, meanining ALL possible IPs, which means all requests are allowed.

Comment: This task has already been marked as answered and doesn't add anything that hasn't been saidid. Please avoid reiterating information as new answers, especially in questions already marked as answered.